# How to create an instance of a Generic class where type constraints to same generic class

Tags: c#, oop, generics

Suppose a class defined as below,

```
public class MyGeneric<T> where T : MyGeneric<T>
    {

    }
```

Can we create an object of this class? If not, why does this exist?
I'm asking this of my curiosity and don't have an in depth knowledge in C#.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by inheriting from `MyGeneric`:

```cs
public class MyGeneric<T> where T : MyGeneric<T>
{
}

class MyGenericChild : MyGeneric<MyGenericChild>
{
}

var myGenericChild = new MyGenericChild();
var myGeneric = new MyGeneric<MyGenericChild>();
```

This is helpful when there is need to create type-specific members in the base class, specific to the actual descendant.

```cs
public class MyGeneric<T> where T : MyGeneric<T>
{
    public void Do(T t)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class MyGenericChild : MyGeneric<MyGenericChild>
{
    // Do for MyGenericChild will accept only MyGenericChild and it's descendants 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's useful when you have a class hierarchy, and you want to be able to write methods in the base class which return instances of the derived class (such as `this`):

```
public abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>
{
    public T WithFoo(int foo)
    {
        // ...
        return (T)this;
    }
}

public class Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    // ...
}

Derived d = new Derived().WithFoo(3);
```

---

Of course, this doesn't stop someone from writing:

```
public class Other : Base<Derived> { }
```

... and the only way to get around this is with a runtime check, which can be ugly:

```
public Base()
{
    Trace.Assert(typeof(T) == this.GetType());
}
```

Some other languages have specific keywords to cover this case.

Comment: Are you sure WithFoo is returning T? Or its Base<T>?

Comment: It's returning `T`. In this case `T` is `Derived` -- it's the type of the derived class, i.e. the thing which is passed to `Base<...>`. If it returned `Base<T>`, then `Derived d = new Derived().WithFoo(3)` would fail, as `WithFoo` wouldn't return a `Derived`

Comment: Compiler error `Base<T> cannot be converted to T`